# Golang app deployment in docker container

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

i need to deploy go restful app into Docker container.

My project has the following structure

go_proj

> ```
>   |- bin
>   |- src |
>   |      |- com.example |
>   |      |              |- web_service.go
>   |      |
>   |      |- github.com.gorilla.mux |
>   |                                | - ...
>   |- Dockerfile
> ```

How should my Dockerfile look like?
And maybe I should download the library(mux) from the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some experience with deploying Go apps using Docker.

### TL;DR

This is how my project looks like in `${GOPATH}/src/github.com/githubhandle/project`

```
main.go
vendor.conf
vendor/
    github.com/gorilla/mux
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus
    github.com/bshuster-repo/logrus-logstash-hook
    ...
Dockerfile
```

And the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM golang:1.8
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install
EXPOSE [8080]
ENTRYPOINT ["go-wrapper", "run", "main.go"]
```

Pretty much

### Long answer

In general, I like to put my Dockerfile inside the server directory:

```
go/
    src/
        github.com/
            mygithub/
                serverproject/
                    main.go
                    Dockerfile
```

If I am using non standard packages in my projects such as (gorilla/mux) I would probably use [`vndr`](https://github.com/LK4D4/vndr) to create a vendor directory where I put all these packages and manage their versions.

After that my Dockerfile would probably look like that:

```
FROM golang:1.8
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install
ENTRYPOINT ["go-wrapper", "run", "main.go"]
```

**Note** You may want to automatically expose port number. For example, adding this line will expose port 8080 inside the container to the host.

```
PORT 8080
```

What is left to do is to build the image from within `go/src/github.com/mygithub/serverproject`:

```
docker build -t serverproject .
```

And to deploy it into a container:

```
docker run -P --rm --name myserver1 serverproject
```

If you want to pass arguments to the server you can do that like the following:

```
docker run -P --rm --name myserver1 serverproject --arg1 --arg2=bla
```

**Note** in case you didn't specify `PORT` in your Dockerfile and would like to expose it to the host, replace `-P` with `-p` before `--name` and specify `<host-port>:<container-port>`:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 ...
```

This will actually port forward from your host to the container.